# Internet explorer and one of its bug

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

Since my last post was difficult to understand, I'll try to explain again my problem but it will be more understandable!

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 (personally, but maybe clients won't use this version, I don't really know).

**The context :**
I have a div on which I have an other page that manage a picture, and the picture is actually larger than the div. So I found a script that allow me to move on the picture by click-dragging (the best example I have of something similar is GoogleMap, the map move when you click-drag).
On this image, I have a map with areas (actually, something like 400 areas), and when I click on one of those areas, it opens a new internet page (all areas contains hyperlinks).

**The problem** : Everything works fine except when my cursor move above an area. When I do this (even without clicking) the page seems to stop, the cursor transform to be the not-allowed cursor, and I can't move anymore for something like 4 seconds. After this 4 seconds, it seems that the page refresh herself and then the page works again like nothing happened, and sometimes, IE crash and I have to stop it.
It's kinda handicapping because it makes the page less responsive.

Did someone already have this bug?

Thanks a lot!

(N.B : I will put the code if someone asks me to, but I'm not sure this is really important in that case :/)

**And now the code :** 
Page 1 : the page in which the div is placed :

```
<div id="one">
    <iframe src="index.htm" style="width:100%; height:100%;" alt=""   id="fram"> </iframe>
</div>
```

Page 2 :

```
function startDrag(e) {

    // determine event object
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    // IE uses srcElement, others use target
    var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    if (targ.className != 'dragme') {return};
    // calculate event X, Y coordinates
    window.offsetX = e.clientX;
    window.offsetY = e.clientY;

    // assign default values for top and left properties
    if(!targ.style.left) { targ.style.left='0px'};
    if (!targ.style.top) { targ.style.top='0px'};

    // calculate integer values for top and left 
    // properties
    window.coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
    window.coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);

    drag = true;

    // move div element
        document.onmousemove=dragDiv;

}

 function dragDiv(e) {
    if (!drag) {return};
    if (!e) { var e= window.event};
    var img = "SiteMap.png";
    var targ=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;
    // move div element
        if (coordX+e.clientX-offsetX < 0 && coordX+e.clientX-offsetX > -maxsizeX+divX){
            targ.style.left=coordX+e.clientX-offsetX+'px';
        }
        if (coordY+e.clientY-offsetY< 0 && coordY+e.clientY-offsetY > -maxsizeY+divY){
            targ.style.top=coordY+e.clientY-offsetY+'px';
        }

    return false;
}

function stopDrag() {
    drag=false;
}

</head>
<body>
<img src="SiteMap.png" usemap="#TruView" id="draggable" class="dragme">
<map name="TruView">

<area title="P96N-P-1" shape="circle" coords="5091,347,16" href="P96N-P-1/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P96N-P-2" shape="circle" coords="5105,490,16" href="P96N-P-2/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P96N-P-3" shape="circle" coords="5112,682,16" href="P96N-P-3/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P96N-P-4" shape="circle" coords="5123,808,16" href="P96N-P-4/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P604-P-1" shape="circle" coords="5105,933,16" href="P604-P-1/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P604-P-2" shape="circle" coords="5029,968,16" href="P604-P-2/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P604-P-3" shape="circle" coords="5033,1124,16" href="P604-P-3/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P604-P-4" shape="circle" coords="5100,1168,16" href="P604-P-4/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P98-P-1" shape="circle" coords="5096,1379,16" href="P98-P-1/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P98-P-2" shape="circle" coords="5023,1322,16" href="P98-P-2/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P98-P-3" shape="circle" coords="5094,1351,16" href="P98-P-3/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P98-P-4" shape="circle" coords="5098,1507,16" href="P98-P-4/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P98-P-5" shape="circle" coords="5086,1628,16" href="P98-P-5/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
<area title="P98-P-6" shape="circle" coords="5088,1592,16" href="P98-P-6/TruView.xml" target="_blank">
...
```

Comment: It sounds like we will need the code to work out what's going on. Are you using a library for the click and drag functionality or did you implement it yourself? Does the issue only affect IE11 or other browsers as well?

Comment: I will put the code in 1 min.
It only affect IE, cause my drag and move didn't work on other browsers :/
I'm not using library.

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch actually you are using a library as you say: _"So I found a script that allow me to move on the picture"_ so you should show us the code for that.

Comment: I just edited my post.

Comment: *It only affect IE, cause my drag and move didn't work on other browsers*: So basically, the script doesn't work at all?

Comment: Well, is this comment actually helping me? Or it's just to trash IE? Because that's right, I know that IE is terrible, but it's an obligation to make it work on IE, I don't care about other browsers ;)

Comment: I found another thing that is strange!
When I fly above my areas, during the time nothing works, if i put my cursor on an editor, when it reworks, the program copy-paste the href of the areas I flew where I had my cursor O:

Comment: I just recommend to you the plugin [**Draggabily**](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/). It is written in pure-javascript (no jQuery) and works perfectly out of the box in all browsers and IE>=10. I use this plugin in many projects and all of them works since at least 3 years ago like first day :)

Comment: I just make an answer because someone told me how to solve my problem! But I'll check it the next time, because it'll be probably easier than coding everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make this response because I checked out how to make it works without problems!

The problem come from :

```
function dragDiv(e) {
    if (!drag) {return }; // <- HERE! You have to return false, instead of just return
    if (!e) { var e= window.event};
    //var img = "SiteMap.png";
    var targ=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;
```

If I understood well, it's used to stop the default working of the browser. Something in link with event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault.
I will make other search on it, but here's the solution, if you have something like this too! :)

Comment: I recommend to you change your plugin, this code seems to be horrible to maintain and will cause more problems. And in your own words, it only works in IE, incomprehensible.

Comment: THIS IS SPAAAARTAAAAA!!! :D
yup! maybe if I see that it doesn't work or if I have negatives return, I will check out yours ;)

Comment: Oh, you can make what you want. I don't will downvote you. If this solves your problem there's no reason to downvote. However, I think there are tons of easy-to-use and ready-to-use solutions to make this task.

Comment: Ahah, yup, i'm pretty sure that there are tons of easy-to-use and ready-to-use solutions too. But this time I probably used the wrong way, and finished it the wrong way too :) 
But as I said, if I see problems with my program, i'll look for some of those E-T-U and R-T-U solutions ;), they are probably "better" than my code :)

Comment: Yeah, it's not better, but it's more versatile and reusable. Good luck!